# How the google drive edit history is implemented?

Tags: web-applications, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm implementing a question management system which has bunch of question bank and each bank includes chapters and sections(each section has questions). I need to show history for all above levels:

1. For example :
        User X has added/modified Question Y in Chapter C, Section S.
        User X has added/modified Chapter C, section s.
2. User has shared this question bank with these users.

Please, suggest some tools or database scheme to implement such design.

[image]